# Curves plugin for Maya

Tags: python-3.x, maya, curve, maya-api

I work on a project with curves and sweep on Maya 2022. After testing curves, I'm a little bit dissapointed. Curves are complicated to edit/manipulate. I made some research/tests on different software (houdini, max...) and I would like to try develop a plugin for editing curves in the same way of houdini/max/c4D (a mix keeping best options/editing of these soft). I made some tests (python, openMaya) but my knowledge are limited. I come from AS3/JS so develop in C++ are really intimidating. Help on maya documentation are a bit complicated for me.

So I develop a project (preview) on JS to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

I managed to create curves, to apply fillet but I don't understand how I can interact with curves after creating in a panel, how I can add handle to interact with fillet, etc. I find script to add new attributes for each vertex but I would be able to edit coordinates/fillet-chamfer options and I can't edit curve (control vertex) after creation.

Here is a link for my project (develop in JS) : [Preview](https://73lb.fr/curve_plugin/)

In the right side, I simulate my panel plugin, on left side the outliner. Instructions are on bottom...

Sorry for my awful english.

Every help, tips are welcome. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose what you need are called `manipulators`. You can download the devkit for Maya, there are a lot of examples how to use the API.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna look for manipulators.